# integration by substitution from two variables to one

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In lecture notes I have seen the substitution $t = x\cdot y$ applied for the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(xy)^2}{2}}\cdot y \: dxdy =  \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt \right) ^2$$
Why can two variables be substituted by only one and what are the intermediate steps?

Comment: Actually there's more to it than substituting $t =x\cdot y$.  The integration with respect to $x$ and with respect to $y$ are being factored apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a change of variable $(t,y) = (xy,y)$. The Jacobian matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{t}{y^2}\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so its determinant is $\frac{1}{y}$.

And the double integral becomes
$$\iint_{0<t,y<+\infty} \exp{\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{t^2}{2} \right)}y\frac{1}{y}dtdy =\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt \right) ^2$$

Comment: Top right element of Jacobian should be $-t/y^2$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user351579 yes, It’s a typo, I modified